# Transfer extra space of dual-boot partition to Ubuntu disk

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows, gparted

I got aroudn 1TB of disc space in this computer. There are two partitions, one with 850gb and another one with around 110gb and two OS, Windows 8 and Ubuntu 16.

Ubuntu has 30gb only.

There are 16gb of free space in this 110gb partition, and I want to extend Ubuntu's disc size in 10gb, making it 40gb and will solve my problems for now.

How can I do this?
I see some people saying about using gparted, but I don't want to resize the partitions, I want to incread Ubuntu's disc

[image]

I said 110gb because somewhere in the OS it says 108gb, but in the gparted it says 97gb. i'm talking about `sda2`

Where is ubuntu installed?! why it didn't create a partition?! i guess i choose the windows partition, so both is in sda2, am I wrong?

Comment: Since you have set up your OS on PARTITIONS, resizing the partitions is the only way to do this (unless you want to reformat everything and start all over again). So the gparted suggestion would seem to be appropriate solution for you. Make sure you do a backup of important files first tho.

Comment: i see gparted being used to expand and shrink a partition. but the partition where ubuntu and windows are already have 16gb of free space. if I increase it with gparted for, for example, 50, I will still have a problema: 66gb of free space, and a ubuntu disc of 30gb and full

Comment: In order to INCREASE the size of your ubuntu partition you will need to DECREASE the size of some other partition,  in this case I would imagine you want to decrease the size of your free space partition. So in gparted first decrease the size of the free space partition from current size 16Gb down to 6Gb. Then you should be able to increase your ubuntu partition by 10Gb (30Gb->40Gb).

Comment: not sure if i'm clear: both are in the 110gb partition.

Comment: just added a picture of gparted to illustrate the situation a little better. there are free space. and ubuntu is, some sort of a disc image inside this 100gb partition. if I free 10gb of space of sda2 or sda3, where am I going to put this?!

Comment: Sorry my bad. Just re-read your original post. The free 16Gb is in your 110Gb partition, so you will need to decrease the size of that parition (110Gb->100Gb) then you will have 10Gb you can add to the ubuntu partition.  Each OS should be isolated (a sub-partition) within the larger 110Gb partition. You can check this through gparted (one partition will be NTFS for Windows and the other will likely by EXT4 if you accepted default install for Ubuntu). Sorry I'm at work now and firewall is blocking the image so I probably can't help you further. Anyone else?

Comment: You'll need to free space from the NTFS (or FAT32) partition to give it to EXT4 (which I'm guessing holds sda2 and sda3)